# Статическое приложение QT

Tags: c++, qt, static

Установил статический QT по [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3&v=lwX_urJJOf8).
Установил QWT по [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqFKwF6q7jQ&feature=youtu.be).
В файле **C:\qwt-6.1.3\qwtconfig.pri** закоменчена строка:

```
######################################################################
# Build the static/shared libraries.
# If QwtDll is enabled, a shared library is built, otherwise
# it will be a static library.
######################################################################

#QWT_CONFIG           += QwtDll
```

Создаю маленький проект(код ниже). Динамически все собирается и запускается. Статически собирается, но вылетает ошибка:

> QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

[image: Ошибка при запуске статического приложения]

Путь к статик Qt: C:\Qt\Static5111\5.11.1_Static
Путь к Qwt: C:\qwt-6.1.3
**Проект:**
**qwtTemp.pro**

```
QT       += core gui widgets

TARGET = qwtTemp
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
        widget.h


# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

CONFIG += qwt
```

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <qwt_plot.h>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

    QwtPlot *p;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    p = new QwtPlot();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete p;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    w.p->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Обычная сборка "Отладка"**
[image: Обычная сборка "Отладка"]

---

**Обычная сборка "Выпуск"**
[image: Обычная сборка "Выпуск"]

---

**Статическая сборка "Отладка"**
[image: Статическая сборка "Отладка"]

---

**Статическая сборка "Выпуск"**
[image: Статическая сборка "Выпуск"]

> QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
>   09:37:22: C:/Users/User_ggsk_1/Documents/build-qwtTemp-Desktop_QtStatic_5_11_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/qwtTemp завершился с кодом 3

Comment: Попробуйте сложить все Qt дллки в директорию с исполняемым файлом вашей программы. Ещё есть вариант не совпадения версии qt который вы скачали с установленным рантаймом C++ от микрософт. Возможна она (qt) была собрана с другой версий рантайма.

Comment: Хотя, он явно пишет что [не нравиться](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804238/must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qwidget-invalid-parameter-passed-to-c-r)

Comment: у меня задача собрать статическую сборку. кт и квт собирал с помощью мингв

Answer (score 2):

Вероятнее всего эта проблема инициирована различными условиями компиляции библиотеки и самой программы.
Библиотеки так же надо компилировать в режиме отладки, если приложение собираеться в debug режиме.
Несоблюдение этого соглашения обычно приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Собирайте библиотеки сразу в двух видах, отладочный и режим релиза, если это можно так назвать, без debug символов.

Так же, библиотеки в отладочном режиме обычно отличаются по имени от релиза, например:

- QGLViewerd2.lib - дебаг версия
- QGLViewer2.lib - релиз версия

суффикс `d` присутствует в сборке с режимом отладки. Соответственно надо менять привязки библиотек в MSVC, на нужное имя в зависимости от сборки.

Или использовать `pragma` в коде для автоматического выбора библиотек, например:

```
#if defined __DEBUG__
#pragma comment (lib, "QGLViewerd2.lib")
#else
#pragma comment (lib, "QGLViewer2.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: Проверил. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: У меня в режиме "Релиз" все собирается и в статик и обычно. Но в статик при запуске вылетает ошибка.

Comment: Проверьте в настройках проекта наличие включенных библиотек, если делать дефайн как в примере, из настроек надо выпилить привязку к библиотекам, иначе не очевидно какие и где он берет. Используйте динамические библиотеки на первом этапе. И какая ошибка вылетает? Также? В дефайн надо поправить названия на .dll в таком случае.

Comment: не нашел где нужно "выпилить привязку к библиотекам"

Comment: В MSVC опции проекта - линкер, там привязки к библиотекам, если они есть, надо там удалить, но не пути к самим папкам библиотек. На примере компилятора gcc: `-lQGLViewerd2.lib` удалить, а `-Lc:\\mylib-directory` оставить.

Comment: По обновленным скриншотам у вас явные проблемы с файлами собранных библиотек, он не может найти `libgwtd.a(dll) libQt5Svgd.a(dll)` это дебаг версия библиотеки, скорее всего она не собрана. Тоже самое по статистическими библиотеками, с расширениями `.a`, возможно они собрались с расширением `.lib` ? И чем вы собираете библиотеки и программу? Желательно подробно про версии..